# Не работает valign="top" у ячейки

Tags: html, css

У меня не работает атрибут тега `<td> - valign="top"`. Проблема в том, что этот атрибут работает только тогда, когда в *css* у `body` или `table` выставлено какое-то свойство типа `padding 0` или `height 100%` - в общем, какая-то вещь, логически не связанная с ним, но я забыл, что именно!

Кто помнит, как это включается?

Comment: Может, нужно поставить высоту у ячейки, например, `<td height="200">`.

Comment: не то, там другое

Answer (score 1):

Зачем прописывать стили в `html`, если для этого есть `css`

Пример
http://jsfiddle.net/aehfktLp/

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Кто помнит, как это включается?</td>
        <td>Кто помнит, как это включается?</td>
        <td>У меня не работает атрибут тега td- valign="top" (раньше работало все, я, помню, находил решение этой проблемы).</td>
        <td>Кто помнит, как это включается?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Кто помнит, как это включается?</td>
        <td>Кто помнит, как это включается?</td>
        <td>У меня не работает атрибут тега td- valign="top" (раньше работало все, я, помню, находил решение этой проблемы).</td>
        <td>Кто помнит, как это включается?</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Кто помнит, как это включается?</td>
        <td>Кто помнит, как это включается?</td>
        <td>У меня не работает атрибут тега td- valign="top" (раньше работало все, я, помню, находил решение этой проблемы).</td>
        <td>Кто помнит, как это включается?</td>
    </tr>
</table>



    table {                     
        border-collapse: collapse; 
        border-spacing: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }

    table td, table td * {
        vertical-align: top;
        padding: 5px;
        background: #000;
        color: #fff;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-size: 13px;
        border: 1px solid #fff;
    }
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, скопируйте весь код прямо в сообщение. Ссылки на jsfiddle могут служить только дополнением. Ответы должны быть самодостаточны на случай, если внешние ссылки вдруг накроются.